# "Shade group headings" workaround in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Outlook 2010 removed the option to shade group headings.

Is there any way to workaround it and make something close to the Outlook 2007 look?

Answer (score 3):

I relied heavily on the shade group headings.  The only work around I found is very weak and only seems to work when viewing email (not tasks).  But, it seems better than everything looking completely flat and same-y.

Go to inbox or some other folder ( downside: it seems like you have to do this on all folders)
view tab in ribbon
click view settings button
click conditional formatting button
highlight "unread group headers"  (I know, right, this doesn't seem like it should work...since the majority of my email has been read, but wait for it.)
click the font button
I adjusted the font from default of 8pt to 10pt.
click ok
click ok

now, even if all the messages in the group are read, the groups are enough different to keep me from going blind to try and find something...

I hope this helps.  If anyone finds a way to do this with tasks (and not just in the print-view), please add it here.

I'm using MS Office Standard 2010 Version 14.0.5128.5000 32-bit.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. But that's not good enough for me.. :(

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to do the following in View Settings:

1. Change the "Row Font" in "Other Settings".  I changed mine just to the bold version of the current font.
2. ## 1 results in all messages in looking like they are unread.  So, I added a "Conditional Formatting" rule with the non-bold font.  The condition is "Only items that are:" "read".

Answer (score 1):

I used a variation of this idea - changed the font colour instead (to maroon) as this tends to stand out better IMO.

Can easily be made to apply to all mail folders by:

1. Save view settings as a new view - click Change View, Save Current View As a New View. Make sure newly saved view is applied to Inbox (not a custom view).
2. Apply to multiple folders if desired - click Change View, Apply Current View to Other Mail Folders, select Inbox then click Apply view to subfolders checkbox (bottom left of dialog for all subfolders) or select individual folders as required.

Repeat process to create and apply a similar personalized view for tasks.

Answer (score 1):

To change in Tasks, make the default font for everything bold (this will make Group Headers and Tasks bold).  Then in conditional formatting (View Settings - Conditional Formatting) make a custom rule that all Tasks greater then 0KB have the default font.  This gives the Tasks the defaul font, while leaving the Group headers bolded.

Comment: I like this approach and use it at work too for better visual distinction of items and group headers (especially important when nesting more than 2 or 3 levels of tasks)